# Isekai manga/novel that sounds like "The Rising of the Shield Hero" novel

Tags: story-identification, isekai

I'm trying to find this novel that I read when I first started out reading these types of novels. I want to try to find it now that I'm watching the Shield Hero anime just to see what happens. It's been years and I've forgotten what it was called but I remember three things that happen in different chapters of the novel.

1. There was a time that the main character was in the forest and either had a bird creature companion or found it in the forest. Essentially he enchanted the bird creature with elemental abilities to fight and defeat a hound monster. Later he had dozen of these small bird creatures.
2. One part of a chapter shows that the princess was looking down at him and his group from her room inside the castle.  She reflects what happened to both of them in regret, or maybe she encounters the god paradox of him.
3. Last but not least, his god-version of himself was basically watching his mortal self. However there was a time where his god paradox and other gods was casually chatting to each other. At that time the god-him tried to indirectly convince two characters to do the things he wanted, but both of them went with their own decision. This caused the other gods to fight over those two characters because they saw them having potential, since they ignored the main character's god-version of him being the strongest god.

Comment: Can you describe what this "god paradox" is that you keep referring to?

Comment: Hi welcome to SF&F!  I've tried to clean up the language a bit to make this more clear; you can revert any changes I've made that are incorrect.  You make a couple of references to reading this a while ago ("it's been years") but we have no idea how long ago that was; please try to specify a more concrete range of years.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots this "god paradox"  I am describing is actually the main character. Somehow he is able to look at his mortal self in the past and can make changes to it .

Comment: @DavidW i think that was like 5 years ago